# "Cannot resolve symbol" in xml files in Intellij IDEA

Tags: xml, intellij-idea

I've got this error in every xml file in my project and all tags appears in red. XSD's are located in external library but I have them under Project/Libraries. When I was using IDEA CE v13 all was fine but after I updated to 14 version it has stopped resolving xml files. If anyone else has solved this please give some advices. Tnx!

PS. Im using Mac OS 10.10.4 and IDEA CE 14.1.4

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the external xsd to be recognized by the IDEA.
Go to:

File > Settings > Language & Frameworks > Schemas & DTDs

and add there your dtd from the external jar.

Comment: I have got a few files for one schema and idea recognize only first one, so it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug starting at version 14.0.3 of Community Edition